# Making Python script executable and adding packages (Windows)

Tags: python, user-interface, installation, package, exe

I have a python script with a Gooey GUI that I want to send to other people at my work, so they can use the application on their computers without having to deal with any code.

For that, I need to make the python script executable. I have found a few tutorials online, so that won't be too much of a problem (I hope). However, I also want to add to that application the packages that I am using so when someone downloads the .exe file, they also download the packages necessary to run it. Is that possible?

for example, when they download the .exe python script, I want to automatically install numpy, pandas, and Gooey

An easy option would be anaconda, but unfortunately Gooey doesn't seem to work well with Jupyter :(

Comment: [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) taking care about all dependencies

Comment: thanks! I ran the command pyinstaller nameofscript.py and the .exe app is in the dist file, but when I click on it, only the command prompt opens but not the GUI..do you think it could be something in the code?

Comment: Probably some libs weren't (correctly) included. You can try debug it yourself or try using other utlilties: [Auto PY to EXE](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)

Answer (score 0):

i encountered this few hours ago. please try converting your file to .exe by typing

```
pyinstaller --onefile path/to/your/file.exe
```

then open a cmd and run

```
yourfile.exe
```

you should see your errors specifically and start debugging there. sorry for my format, i'm using a phone right now. hopr this helps

Comment: thanks! I'm getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

Comment: may i see your code? i can't promise to solve it but i can try

Comment: it looks like a lot of code, but it's pretty simple: user inputs 3 files, I append them according to a list of number, separates number by negative or positive, fills some blanks/NaN and performs mapping according to some master files, translates words from English to French with .replace and str.replace and finally writes the file to an excel format

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't seem to figure your error. and about you wanting your co-workers to use your program without coding, for what i know, once you convert your program into exe using pyinstaller, all dependencies are taken care of (this is what i know. i might be wrong) this is all i can do. sorry.

Comment: yeah, if pyinstaller worked then all my problems would be solved! haha thank you for trying (:

Comment: try to fix your program in your system and when you do, try pyinstaller again. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used this to package Gooey apps into an exe: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/